# jdbc string sql server character encoding

Tags: java, sql-server, utf-8

If I have a jdbc string such as...

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

How do you say "connect with character encoding as utf-8 like you can if you were connecting with mysql?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, there is no such [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx) in the [URL schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx). But you probably don't need it anyway. The JDBC driver will take your strings in Java Unicode and return all values in Java Unicode. In Java it does not matter which character encoding the driver uses for communication with the DB (unless you do something really unusual, like trying to work around database bugs, or your database is not aware of the encoding of its content).

Comment: It's because the é character in a String returns as &#233; and i've already set the outputwriter as utf-8

Comment: "&#233;" is a XML character entity and should not have anything to do with UTF-8. What do you see when you look at the table in Management Studio, the character or the entity? What's the column type, (var)char or XML?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try, [as in Php,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626307%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://serverName\instanceName;CharacterSet=UTF-8
```

Regards,
 stéphane